# Reference request for tensor analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, tensors

I took a look at other similar questions, such as [Tensor Book Recommendation Request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437010/tensor-book-recommendation-request) but did not get what I am looking for.

What I have:

- first course in linear algebra, tensor calculus
- background in engineering sciences

What I am looking for:

- Tensor analysis introductory book (Not completely math oriented. It should be readable for someone non-math major.)
- I know basics and properties of tensor. I understand $v'_i=Q_{ji}v_i$ that tensor $Q$ transforms vector $v$ to get $v'$ but I do not understand tensor as linear mapping.
- Trying to understand dual space (dual vector space). I checked few linear algebra books, such as Shilov G. E., but didn't get what I was looking for. (as per question [Where to start learning Linear Algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/where-to-start-learning-linear-algebra)). Unfortunately, my linear algebra course did not discuss dual vector spaces.

P.S. I saw questions asking book recommendation getting closed. But 'book recommendation' and 'reference request' are active tags in SE Mathematics, so I don't see any reason why. Secondly, there are already several questions out there on the website.

Comment: Personally I like book requests.

Comment: If you like the classical index approach [Lovelock and Rund](https://www.amazon.com/Tensors-Differential-Variational-Principles-Mathematics/dp/0486658406) is pretty good (and cheap).  Though I personally prefer more modern (read: abstract) books like [Renteln](https://www.amazon.com/Manifolds-Tensors-Forms-Introduction-Mathematicians/dp/1107042194).